# python почему не работает Lru_cache для простой функции из примера

Tags: python, python-3.x, кэширование

Подскажите почему `не работает @lru_cache` (из functools) для такой простой функции,хотел изучить кэширование взял простой пример и то не работает у меня (python ~ 3.9)

```
from functools import lru_cache
import time

@lru_cache(maxsize=10)
def test(num):
    result = 0
    for i in range(num):
        result += i
    return result


start = time.time()
test(num=100000000)
end = time.time()
print(f"result 1: {end - start}")
print(test.cache_info())
```

> Выполняю функцию что с декоратором lru_cache что без него, без разницы вообще :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смотри, декоратор `@lru_cache` используется для мемоизации рекурсивных функций. В твоём случае вообще нет смысла мемоизировать, т.к. функция вызывается один раз и в ней работает цикл. Чтобы что-то мемоизировать - надо сначала хоть одну отправную точку получить. У тебя её нет, потому происходит чистый подсчёт большого числа и заканчивается.

Вот тебе простой пример, чтобы сравнить на сколько быстро работает с ним и без него:

```
from functools import lru_cache
import time

@lru_cache(maxsize=10)
def test(num, res):
    if num == res:
        return res
    return test(num+1, res)
start = time.time()
for i in range(1,100):
    test(i, 100)
end = time.time()
print(f"result 1: {end - start}")
print(test.cache_info())
```

### UPDATE

Вот пример на котором легче будет заметить разницу в работе программ

```
from functools import lru_cache
import time
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(8000000) # Поставил чтобы увеличить максимальное кол-во рекурсий

@lru_cache(maxsize=10)
def test(num, res):
    if num == res:
        return res
    if num % 1000 == 0:
        return test(num+1000, res)
    if num % 100 == 0:
        return test(num+100, res)
    if num % 10 == 0:
        return test(num+10, res)
    if num % 2 == 0:
        return test(num+2, res)
    return test(num+1, res)
start = time.time()
for i in range(1,100):
    test(i, 10**7)
end = time.time()
print(f"result 1: {end - start}")
print(test.cache_info())
```

Comment: Программа не столько долго работает, но видно что сокращается работа в разы. Если поставишь `None` вместо `maxsize=10`, то вообще летать будет ;)

Comment: Все понял терь ) Thanks you too mach...

Answer (score 1):

Ну, про то, что `lru_cache` к вашей задаче не подходит, вам уже написали. К каждой функции нужен правильный подход, чтобы её ускорить. Функция, в которой есть внутри цикл (а ещё лучше два вложенных цикла), довольно часто хорошо ускоряется с помощью декоратора `numba.njit()`, и если повезёт, то ускорение будет где-то на 2 порядка. Проверить это можно так на вашем коде - ничего не меняем в нём, просто используем другой декоратор:

```
import time
from numba import njit

@njit()
def test(num):
    result = 0
    for i in range(num):
        result += i
    return result

start = time.time()
test(num=100_000_000)
end = time.time()
print(f"result 1: {end - start}")
# result 1: 0.14800786972045898
```

Но есть и другие варианты, например, можно использовать библиотеку `numpy`, и ускорение будет тоже очень большое, но тут придётся немного переписать код, например, так:

```
import time
import numpy as np

def test(num):
    return np.arange(num).sum()

start = time.time()
test(num=100_000_000)
end = time.time()
print(f"result 1: {end - start}")
# result 1: 0.24969029426574707
```

Важно знать, какие структуры данных и библиотеки в каком случае лучше использовать. Нет какого-то одного универсального средства. Зато есть много разных, нужно их знать и уметь применять.

P.S. Кстати, если убрать из вашей функции цикл и просто просуммировать сразу `range`, то это уже будет работать в несколько раз быстрее без всяких декораторов и дополнительных библиотек:

```
def test(num):
    return sum(range(num))
```